# Model-morphosis, how do I do this

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

This image manipulation is done with Flash, how can I do this with Html5/JQuery. Drag the bar up or down to see the change.

http://tmagazine.blogs.nytimes.com/2009/09/15/model-morphosis-marc-jacobs-beauty-2/

Comment: I don't think this needs HTML 5. I'm sure there is a jQuery plugin for this but I can't remember its name...

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? I'm investigating doing this w/ou Flash. Is that not a valid question?

Comment: nonono, it's a perfectly valid question but this doesn't need any HTML 5 specific functionality as far as I can see. HTML 4 and jQuery will do fine. Never mind, it's not important

Answer (score 1):

You can create two `<img>` tags super-imposed on top of each other, then adjust the height of a `<div>` containing the upper one as you drag the slider.  (The `<div>` should have `overflow:hidden`)